# JBoss 7.1.1 final jboss deployment structure file

Tags: maven-2, jboss7.x

I have an wierd maven question:

It is possible to generate an jboss-deployment-structure xml file with maven plugins ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you envision this would work? You want maven to create the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file from your projects pom files I assume? Do your dependencies match the jboss module names in all cases? I Doubt it.

Comment: @ jjhavokk Hi, take a look on officiale maven plugins, I have found that with maven-ear-plugin we can create application.xml and jboss-app.xml with maven configuration tags. So, that I would like achieve is to understand if there are some new configuration for jboss 7.x, that permits to create jboss-deployment-architecture.xml, cause i would generate it in automatic way...I Hope that is clear now.